# Python list string to list

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
s= "[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]"
```

and I need to convert that string into a list:

```
l= [7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]
```

the problem is, when I use list(s) I get this:

```
['[', '7', ',', ' ', '9', ',', ' ', '4', '1', ',', ' ', '[', '3', '2', ',', ' ', '6', '7', ']', ']']
```

I am using python 3.2

Comment: What format is the string in? JSON? Python? Other?

Comment: The reason you get what you do is that strings are iterable, with their characters as the entries. If you pass `list` an iterable, it will give you a list containing the entries from the iterable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* do exactly what you asked for by using `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]")
[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]
```

However, you probably want to use a sane serialisation format like JSON in the first place, instead of relying on the string representation of Python objects.  (As a side note, the string you have might even be JSON, since the JSON representation of this particular object would look identical to the Python string representation.  Since you did not mention JSON, I'm assuming this is not what you used to get this string.)

Comment: I am trying to do this because I'm sending the data as a string over a socket, is there a better way?

Comment: @ParkerHoyes: Yes, just any proper serialisation is better.  Have a look at Python's `json` and `pickle` modules, to name two.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ast` module, it has a handy [`.literal_eval()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

l = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

On the python prompt:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s= "[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
s= "[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]"
print ast.literal_eval(s)
# [7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:
package ast: function : literal_eval(node_or_string)

http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#module-ast

Answer (score 0):

It is another answer, But I don't suggest you.Because `exec` is dangerous.

```
>>> s= "[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]"
>>> try:
...   exec 'l = ' + s
...   l
... except Exception as e:
...   e
[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use `eval()`?

```
>>> s = "[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]"
>>> eval(s)
[7, 9, 41, [32, 67]]
```